# Java Rmi UnknownHostException

Tags: java, rmi

I am trying to write a simple RMI file but for some reason it is giving me an *unknown host name* exception. I have tried simply everything before actually asking a question. Here is the code for the project.

RMI interface class:

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface Hello extends Remote {
    String sayHello() throws RemoteException;
}
```

Server Class:

```
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class Server implements Hello {

    public Server() {}

    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            Server obj = new Server();
            Hello stub = (Hello) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj, 0);

            // Bind the remote object's stub in the registry
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            registry.bind("Hello", stub);

            System.err.println("Server ready");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Server exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Client class:

```
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class Client {

    private Client() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String host = (args.length < 1) ? null : args[0];
        try {
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host);
            Hello stub = (Hello) registry.lookup("Hello");
            String response = stub.sayHello();
            System.out.println("response: " + response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Client exception: " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this over localhost this runs completely fine but for the life of me I cannot get this to run over the network across two machines. I've tried:

- Connecting the machines over Wifi.
- Connecting over ethernet so they have addresses like `192.168.1.1` and `192.168.1.2` respectively. Both machines can ping each other fine. If I `nma -PN` the server from the client I can see that port `1099` is open and the `rmiregistry` is running. But not matter what combination of hostnames I try it still doesn't connect the client to the server.

Combinations I've tried for input as host name on client side:

```
rmi://192.168.1.1
rmi://192.168.1.1:1099
```

And maybe tens more with all possible slashes etc. still no clue why this isn't working (even though it works perfectly over localhost). Any ideas would be welcome.

For completeness here is the actualy error I get:

```
 java -classpath classes/ Client
Client exception: java.rmi.UnknownHostException: Unknown host: rmi://192.168.1.1; nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: rmi://192.168.1.1
java.rmi.UnknownHostException: Unknown host: rmi://192.168.1.1; nested exception is:
    java.net.UnknownHostException: rmi://192.168.1.1
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:598)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at Client.main(Client.java:14)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: rmi://192.168.1.1
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:22)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:128)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:595)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Did you try just '192.168.1.1'?  A hostname is the name of the machine, and should not include a 'protocol' - it's not a URI/URL.

Comment: java -classpath classes/ Client here i am not seeing any argument , what argument are you passing to Client main method? both in localhost case and remote computer case?

Comment: I did try 192.168.1.1. As I mentioned I have tried simply all ridiculous combinations by now and they don't work.
The argument isn't there because this error was from a different run where I was simply hard coding the hostname as "rmi://192.168.1.2" etc. to make sure the code wasn't the problem.

Comment: @user1822343 So what is the current problem when you try to call `LocateRegistry.getRegistry("192.168.1.1")`? And is that really the IP address of the server? It looks more like a router address to me.

Comment: This was resolved. I'll just post my own solution. Apparently running the server like java -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.1.1 Server solves the problem. When the client calls the server and gets back a stub, this stub contains this property and java sets this property to localhost by default. That is why it seems even though your client is connecting to a remote host, it crashes saying connection refused on localhost.

Answer (score 3):

This was resolved. I'll just post my own solution. Apparently running the server like this works: java -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.1.1 Server.The problem was that when the client calls the server and gets back a stub, this stub contains this property and java sets this property to localhost by default, even if you bind the server to an ip when creating a registry. That is why it seems even though your client is connecting to a remote host, it crashes saying connection refused on localhost because the stub it has contains localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment on the mapping between host name and IP: you can name you locator whatever you like but then you will have to insert an entry in your hosts file (C:\Windows\system32...\hosts), e.g.

```
127.0.0.1  rmihost1
```

Then you can rmihost1 in the call:

```
LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host, port);
```